# Como ativar e desativar um botão de login em Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Estou criando uma tela de login, quero que: caso o usuário não tenha digitado seu documento (username) o botão de login fique desabilitado.

```
import UIKit

class loginManager: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var document: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            document.delegate = self
            loginButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
    extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
        
        extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
            func documentDidEndEditing(_ document: UITextField) {
                if document.text?.isEmpty == false {
                    loginButton.isEnabled = true
                } else {
                    loginButton.isEnabled = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá @YAGOCOMY, o problema com a sua implementação é que você incluiu uma extensão dentro de outra:

```
import UIKit

class LoginManagerViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var document: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    document.delegate = self
    loginButton.isEnabled = false
  }
}

extension LoginManagerViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
  func documentDidEndEditing(_ document: UITextField) {
    if document.text?.isEmpty == false {
        loginButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        loginButton.isEnabled = false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [extensões](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) adicionam nova funcionalidade a uma classe, estrutura, enumeração ou tipo de protocolo existente. Isso inclui a capacidade de estender os tipos para os quais você não tem acesso ao código-fonte original (conhecido como modelagem retroativa). As extensões são semelhantes às categorias em Objective-C. (Ao contrário das categorias Objective-C, as extensões Swift não têm nomes.)

As extensões em Swift podem:

- Adicionar propriedades de instância computadas e propriedades de tipo computado
- Definir métodos de instância e métodos de tipo
- Fornece novos inicializadores
- Definir subscritos
- Defina e use novos tipos aninhados
- Faça um tipo existente em conformidade com um protocolo

Você pode usar desta forma:

```
class LoginManagerViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

}
```

ou desta forma:

```
class LoginManagerViewController: UIViewController {
    ....
}
extension LoginManagerViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
   
}
```